# Use static function on interface class .Net Framework 4.5

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, static-methods

I have used static functions in my interface class.

If I don't put definition in interface,

```
 public interface CPT
 {
    public static void authenticate(CPTIntegrationUser user);
 }
```

it gives error as Method must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial

and if I declare a body,

```
public interface CPT
{
  public static void authenticate(CPTIntegrationUser user) {}
}
```

it gives error as Error CS8701: Target runtime doesn't support default interface implementation. (CS8701)

Comment: Please show some code

Comment: I have added code in question , you can check now

Comment: Short answer - you can't do this in .NET Framework. If you want default implementations or static methods on an interface, you need to use .NET Core / .NET 5+.